# Change data context when using UserControls

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm using a simple main window that contains 2 custom User Controls (that i've created)
those user controls has ModelView code file for each (im using MVVM pattern).
each ModelView file contains single Command (and command implementation of Execute and CanExecute).
The problem is that when i need to active each command (through the MainWindow cause the main window holds those custom user controls) i need to change the DataContext
of the **Main window** to the ViewModel of the control that is currently in focus otherwisw i cant execute the command (the Command binding inside the UserControl.xaml cant find the Command).
I think that tracking after focused UserControl in order to change the MainWindow DataContext is not the way.
Is anyone faced this kind of problem before ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of solving this is by creating a ViewModel for the main window and add two properties to this VM, one for each ViewModel you created before.

This way you can assign the new VM to the DataContext of the Window and Bind the DataContext of each user control to one of the properties.

Put the commands on the correct VM where you want to use it.
Does this make sense?

BTW: you call ModelView what I'd call ViewModel.